# Applescript delete mail by subject

Tags: email, applescript

Is there a way to delete mails by the subject, i'm trying to make an applescript that deletes mails with a certain subject from my 'Sent' mailbox. I have tried these scripts this with a test mail:

```
    tell application "Mail"
    set theMails to every message of (every mailbox whose name is "Sent") whose subject is "Test Mail"
delete theMails
    end tell
```

and:

```
tell application "Mail"
set theMails to {every message of inbox "Sent" whose subject is "Test Mail"}
delete theMails
end tell
```

Both scripts didn't work, and I didn't understand the returned errors so I could not find a solution. Help appriciated!

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code bellow works. better to use word "contains" instead of trying exact match of the subject

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theMails to {every message of sent mailbox whose subject contains "Test Mail"}
    delete theMails 
end tell
```

Comment: sorry I made typo mistake : remove the "{"